# Restrict Powershell from printing input commands to output stream

Tags: java, powershell-5.1

I am using Java ProcessStream to write input commands to powershell on my local machine. Now, the problem is that along with the output, I am seeing input commands as well. How can I restrict input command from being shown on the output.

Below is the code to reproduce the same:

```
public class Example {
    public static boolean isAlive(Process o) {
        try {
            p.exitValue();
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {return true;}
    }
    
    public stati void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream out = process.getInputStream();
        OutputStream in = process.getOutputStream();
        String bufferString = "echo hello \n";
        byte[] buffer = bufferString.getBytes();
        int n = buffer.length;
        
        in.write(buffer, 0, n);
        in.flush();
        
        while(isAlive(process)) {
            int no = out.available();
            if (no >0) {
                int m = out.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(no, buffer.length));
                System.out.println(new String(buffer, 0, m));
            }
        }
    }
}

OUTPUT:

PS C://> echo hello
hello
```

I need only "hello" in output.

Comment: I'm afraid it is impossible to get rid of `PS C://>` part. So you have to filter your input stream yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (but the java program never terminates and I have to kill it).

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Example {
    public static boolean isAlive(Process p) {
        try {
            p.exitValue();
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("powershell", "-NoLogo");
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        try (InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
             BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
            OutputStream in = process.getOutputStream();
            String bufferString = "echo hello" + System.lineSeparator();
            byte[] buffer = bufferString.getBytes();
            in.write(buffer);
            in.flush();
            while (isAlive(process)) {
                String line = out.readLine();
                if (!line.startsWith("PS")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output produced by the above code is simply:

```
hello
```

@talex mentioned the following in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021307/restrict-powershell-from-printing-input-commands-to-output-stream#comment118467925_67021307) to your question:

> it is impossible to get rid of `PS C://>` part

This is not true since you can customize the *PowerShell* [prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7.1) but you wrote that you don't want to see the `echo hello` in the output and that is not possible and therefore, as @talex mentioned:

> you have to filter your input stream yourself

Not displaying `echo hello` means not displaying the entered command. Imagine that you open a *PowerShell* window and don't see the command you entered but after you hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you want to see the output. So I don't think that there is a way to not display `echo hello` and therefore, in the above code, I don't print lines that start with the *PowerShell* prompt.

You can find details about launching *PowerShell* in [about_PowerShell_exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: Thanks Abra for the detailed answer. But my use case is to allow "\n" as part of command. For e.g. command can be: "echo x; \n echo y". The above code will not remove "echo y" part of the command.